# 404 Error on Custom Post Type / Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, 404-error, permalinks

I have a registered post type with 'rewrite' set as slug=>cpt_name, with_front=>true.

```
register_post_type( 'objection_handling',
                   array(
                                       'rewrite' => array(
                                            'slug' => 'objection_handling',
                                            'with_front' => true
                                            )
```

I then have a wp_list_pages function with an argument as post_type=>cpt_name. This function successfully displays an unordered list of my custom post type.

I then have custom taxonomies with rewrite=>false.

```
register_taxonomy(
                  'objection_topics',
                  'objection_handling',
                  array(
                        'hierarchical' => true,
                        'public' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'rewrite' => false,
                        'labels' => array(
                                          'name' => __( 'Objection Handling Topics' ),
                                          'singular_name' => __( 'Objection Handling Topic' ),
                                          'hierarchical' => true
                                          ),
                        )
                  );
```

Now I'm thinking this will output a URL like : /objection_handling/[title-of-page] but I'm getting 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the slug for the taxonomy.

But it seems that you are trying to create a archive? Then you should create a new template file with the taxonomy name instead. But then you are loosing the ability to add a description to the page.

Comment: I rewrote the question. Because I'm using a custom post type, wouldn't I want the URL to be /objection_handling/[objection_topic] ?

Comment: read about the rewrite argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question! For the record, ensure that you flush rewrite rules after change post types and taxonomies.

You can do this by visiting `Settings > Permalinks` in the Dashboard, or programmatically, as the [Bones theme](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones) does:

```
// Flush rewrite rules for custom post types
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'bones_flush_rewrite_rules' );

// Flush your rewrite rules
function bones_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```